# Sequelize expecting Integer despite of making the type for the field as Float

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a model as below:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
  username: process.env.PGUSER,
  password: process.env.PGPASS,
  host: process.env.PGHOST,
  port: process.env.PGPORT,
  dialect: "postgres"
});

var MessageRating = sequelize.define(
  "MessageRating",
  {
    chatId: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    ratingType: {
      type: Sequelize.ENUM,
      values: ["NEGATIVE", "POSITIVE", "NEUTRAL", "MIXED"],
      allowNull: false
    },
    rating: {
      type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
      allowNull: false
    }
  },
  {
    indexes: [
      {
        unique: false,
        fields: ["ratingType"]
      }
    ]
  }
);

module.exports = MessageRating;
```

I'm trying to create a table using this model using the following code :

```
 var messageRatingStored = sequelize
          .sync()
          .then(() =>
            MessageRating.create({
              chatId: chatId,
              ratingType: amazonComprehendResult.ResultList[0].Sentiment,
              rating: roundOffRating
            })
          )
          .then(messageRating => {
            console.log("MessageRating json", messageRating.toJSON());
          });
```

Whenever I run the code it throws error: "Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for integer: "0.82""

https://gist.github.com/BikalNepal/51fd28f877b422fcc16825d61cd95847

I tried using a static integer value (82, 10 etc) instead of "roundOffRating" (which gives decimal) and it stores perfectly without errors. Since I'm not using Integer for the type of rating in the model, why is it still expecting integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You updated your Sequelize model, but have you updated the database table itself ?

Using `sequelize.sync()` only creates missing tables. It does not update existing ones. Using `sequelize.sync({force: true})` will drop all tables and recreate them, meaning your field will be effectively a float, but you will lose all data present in the database.

You can update your field in the database, without losing data, with the following alter statement:

```sql
ALTER TABLE MessageRating ALTER COLUMN rating TYPE float;
```

Read more about [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html).

**A useful tip:** Sequelize propagates errors from the database as `SequelizeDatabaseError` errors. When you see this type of error coming from your code, you can be sure the error comes from the database and not sequelize itself.

Comment: Yes, I did the same. The type for rating was still 'int4' although I have changed it to be a Float in the model. Using dbeaver, I changed it to 'float8' and got rid of the error. 

Do I always have to do this (alter the database itself) when I want to change my model? And I don't want to lose all the data just to add a new field to a model or change a type, that means no {force: true} as well.

Comment: Yes you will have to manually redo any model change in your database. I believe it is so because some data types cannot be implicitely updated (string to int for example). Also, please mark my answer as accepted If you think it will help future viewers.